# Test AWS Cognito login with Postman

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to test the Lambda functions that I have created and which sit behind a Cognito login.

My Lambda functions require that `cognitoIdentityId` is set in order to identitfy the user.

I've been following the [Use Postman to Call a REST API tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html) in the Amazon docs. However, this tutorial only shows how to authenticate with IAM credentials and not Cognito User Credentials which means that `cognitoIdentityId` is set to `null`.

How does one go about integrating a Cognito User login with Postman?

Comment: Anyone figure this out? Stuck on the same issue rn

Comment: did you solve it? if yes, how?

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to see it with:

```
 console.log(event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId);
```